# How to make Outlook forward emails based on subject line for multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook

**Issue**

I understand MS Outlook rules enough to know how to make rules forward emails based on the subject and body line. The issue I'm having is I have an Excel sheet that has a couple hundred lines that are my criteria on what needs to be sent out.

**Example**

[image: Table]

So if an email comes in with the subject containing "111" then it will forward the email "Email1@gmail.com" and so on and so forth.

So far I've found ways to create folder rules to moving certain subjects into certain folders. But I can't seem to find a way to use VBA or anything to do the same thing based on forwarding

Comment: It isn't clear what the problem is.  You show an example of what you're able to accomplish, but no real information of the problem, and no explanation of why you think you need VBA.

Comment: The account that you have logged into outlook... is it a gmail account as well? Office365 account? On prem exchange? Maybe be best to not use outlook to do the forwarding and just log into the gmail account and set 3 identical forwarding filters.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840066/forward-email-with-its-attachment-in-outlook-2010] (stackoverflow.com) this should clear up forwarding in VBA.  Just do your magic on opening your attachment file and choosing your criteria.  Let us know if you need help with that [duplicate]

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear enough in my post and sorry for not doing well. So the problem is I'm trying to create like maybe 200+ rules or so that based on the ID number would forward an email to the email that matches the subject of that ID.I also thought I could use VBA cause I tried searching this problem up and someone used VBA to bulk make rules to move certain emails with subjects go into certain folders.

Comment: The issue with that is that I want to bulk make rules because we have a lot of them